# Yocto SDK build does not include headers for gnutls

Tags: yocto

When I build my sdk with `bitbake -c populate_sdk <imagename>` I am always missing the headers for gnutls.

The packaging system seems to find the headers just fine, because in the gnutls build directory you can find these files...

```
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/pkcs7.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/urls.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/dtls.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/ocsp.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/tpm.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/abstract.h
packages-split/gnutls-dev/usr/include/gnutls/system-keys.h
... etc ...
```

The libraries get installed as part of the SDK, but the headers do not.

I have applications that DEPENDs on gnutls, so you would expect it to show up in the SDK automatically.  I also added this line to my distro configuration:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append += " gnutls-dev"
```

I tried an incremental build, and when that didn't work I tried a completely clean build (deleted tmp and sstatecache directories).  I get a functional SDK, but still no gnutls headers.

I also tried editing the gnutls_3.6.13.bb recipe to include the following:

```
FILES_${PN}-dev += "${libdir}/gnutls/*"
```

Of course, that line shouldn't be required because the contents of libdir are supposed be packaged for -dev automatically but I tried it anyway.  No joy.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: Two years later...were you able to figure out what was going on here (can you answer your own question at this point :))? I'm seeing the same thing even if I manually add gnutls-dev to the IMAGE_INSTALL for the image I'm generating the SDK from.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `INCOMPATIBLE_LICENSE` by

```
bitbake -e image recipe > eout.txt
```

and then seraching `eout.txt`.

It may be filtering out things like GPLv3 so it isn't installed into the rootfs generated.